# How to use string in select in Entity Framework on .NET 6

Tags: entity-framework, .net-6.0

I want to make a dynamic query in Entity Framework like this:

```
var query = db.Select("id, name")
```

I try to use `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` library also test https://github.com/aaubry/DynamicQuery

but it is not working.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` library modify select:

```
  var query=db.Student.Select("new(Id,Name)").ToDynamicList()
```